# How to simplify the iteration through rows in Openpyxl?

Tags: iteration, row, openpyxl

Hello I have came out with this solution to iterate throught several rows (by specifying the row number '2', '3', '4', exc), however I would like to do the same iteration in a different context where there are way more rows. 
What command shall I use instead of specifing the number of row?

```
for col in range(3, 4 + 1):
for row in range(2, 14):
    Jan = database[str(get_column_letter(col)) + '2'].value
    Feb = database[str(get_column_letter(col)) + '3'].value
    Mar = database[str(get_column_letter(col)) + '4'].value
    Apr = database[str(get_column_letter(col)) + '5'].value
    May = database[str(get_column_letter(col)) + '6'].value
    Jun = database[str(get_column_letter(col)) + '7'].value
    Jul = database[str(get_column_letter(col)) + '8'].value
    Aug = database[str(get_column_letter(col)) + '9'].value
    Sep = database[str(get_column_letter(col)) + '10'].value
    Oct = database[str(get_column_letter(col)) + '11'].value
    Nov = database[str(get_column_letter(col)) + '12'].value
    Dec = database[str(get_column_letter(col)) + '13'].value
```

the result I am trying to obtain is this:
{'Jan': [218, 124], 'Feb': [541, 874], 'Mar': [215, 156], 'Apr': [365, 189], 'May': [245, 645], 'Jun': [542, 245], 'Jul': [542, 654], 'Aug': [987, 354], 'Sep': [167, 369], 'Oct': [367, 785], 'Nov': [174, 412], 'Dec': [841, 213]}
considering this structure of data on excel:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Charlie Clark has said, this is covered in the documentation. Here is the code I have used using the [openpyxl docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells):

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
from itertools import zip_longest

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []

elems = []

for (row1,row2,row3) in zip_longest(ws['A1':'A13'],ws['B1':'B13'],ws['C1':'C13']):
    for cell1,cell2,cell3 in zip_longest(row1,row2,row3):


       col1.append(ws.cell(row=cell1.row,column=column_index_from_string(cell1.column)).value)

       col2.append(ws.cell(row=cell2.row,column=column_index_from_string(cell2.column)).value)

       col3.append(ws.cell(row=cell3.row,column=column_index_from_string(cell3.column)).value)

for count,elem in enumerate(zip(col1,col2,col3),1):
    print(elem)
    elems.append(elem)

dict_answer = {x[0]:list(x[1:3]) for x in elems}
print(dict_answer)
```

Please make sure in future to read the docs and search previous queries before asking your own